# Value of optional type must be unwrapped to a value of type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to have a sceneView load a scene but I get the error *Value of optional type 'SCNScene?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'SCNScene'* With options of *Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'* or *Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'*

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/CDMTEST1");

        VirtualObject.readCoreData()
    }
```

Error message : *Value of optional type 'SCNScene?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'SCNScene'*
*Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'*
*Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let scene = SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/CDMTEST1"){
    sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

you need to pass a value not a optional since **SCNScene(named: "Models.scnassets/CDMTEST1")** is optional since may return nil since it fails.

Comment: This context is better suited to force unwrapping, or conditional wrapping and then `fatalError`ing with a custom message. Not finding an asset file is a critical and unrecoverable error, the application shouldn't continue without it. It's best to make it obvious with a crash, then have silent failure